# How to get the distinct record from a Table and delete it

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, distinct

I am working on a plugin on Delete button, when ever I delete any selected record all the distinct(Selected record) should be deleted as well.

In my case I have an Attendee which is invited in a meeting, The Attendee also have some discussion point records and Action Items records in it, As per the requirement when I will delete my Meeting Attendee it should delete this Attendee where it has any discussion point record and Action items record.Need help on this regard.

Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages;

namespace SFDSendEmail.SFDDeleteAttendee.Class
{
    public class SFDDeleteAttendee : IPlugin
    {
        Guid Internaluser;
        Guid Externaluser;
        private IOrganizationService _sdk = null;
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            try
            {
                // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
                IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
                    serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
                IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                _sdk = (IOrganizationService)factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

                if (context.IsExecutingOffline || context.IsOfflinePlayback)
                    return;

                // The InputParameters collection contains all the data passed 
                // in the message request.
                if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
                    context.InputParameters["Target"] is EntityReference)
                {

                    // EntityReference RequiredAttendee = context.InputParameters["new_requiredattendee"] as EntityReference;
                    // Entity entity = _sdk.Retrieve("new_requiredattendee", ((EntityReference)RequiredAttendee["new_requiredattendeeid"]).Id, new ColumnSet(true));
                    // Entity eUser = _sdk.Retrieve(RequiredAttendee.LogicalName, RequiredAttendee.Id, new ColumnSet(true));

                    EntityReference RequiredAttendee = (EntityReference)context.InputParameters["Target"];
                    Entity eUser = _sdk.Retrieve(RequiredAttendee.LogicalName, RequiredAttendee.Id, new ColumnSet(true));
                    if (context.MessageName == "Delete")
                    {
                        if (eUser.LogicalName != "new_requiredattendee")
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //If User Selects the Interner User for Deletion
                            if (eUser.Attributes.Contains("new_internaluser"))
                            {
                                //Save Internal User ID
                                Internaluser = ((EntityReference)eUser["new_internaluser"]).Id;
                                //Function to fetch the Meeting Attendee with the Above ID
                                Guid VerifyAttendee = VerifyMeetingAttendee(eUser,_sdk,Internaluser);
                                //If its the Meeting Attendee
                                if (VerifyAttendee != null)
                                  {
                                      //Get the Attendee with its Discussion Point
                                      Guid AttendeewithDp = VerifyDPMeetingAttendee(eUser, _sdk, Internaluser);
                                      if (AttendeewithDp != null)
                                      {
                                          //Get the Attendee with Action item
                                          Guid AttendeewithAI = VerifyAIMeetingAttendee(eUser, _sdk, Internaluser);
                                          if (AttendeewithAI != null)
                                          {
                                              //DO your code here....................................
                                              _sdk.Delete("new_requiredattendee", AttendeewithAI);
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }    
                            }
                            //If User Selects the Interner User for Deletion
                            else if (eUser.Attributes.Contains("new_externaluser"))
                            {
                                //Save Internal User ID
                                Externaluser = ((EntityReference)eUser.Attributes["new_externaluser"]).Id;

                                //Function to fetch the Meeting Attendee with the Above ID
                                Guid verifyExternalAttendee = VerifyExternalMeetingAttendee(eUser,_sdk,Externaluser);
                                if (verifyExternalAttendee != null)
                                {
                                    //Get the Attendee with its Discussion Point
                                    Guid EXAttendeewithDp = VerifyEXDPMeetingAttendee(eUser, _sdk, Externaluser);
                                    if (EXAttendeewithDp != null)
                                    {
                                        //Get the Attendee with Action item
                                        Guid EXAttendeewithAI = VerifyEXAIMeetingAttendee(eUser, _sdk, Externaluser);
                                        if (EXAttendeewithAI != null)
                                        {
                                            //DO your code here....................................
                                            _sdk.Delete("new_requiredattendee", EXAttendeewithAI);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in the plug-in.", ex);
            }
        }
        //Get Internal Meeting Attendee
        public Guid VerifyMeetingAttendee(Entity RequiredAttendee,IOrganizationService _orgService,Guid user)
        {
            QueryExpression GetMeetingAttendees = new QueryExpression();
            GetMeetingAttendees.EntityName = "new_requiredattendee";
            GetMeetingAttendees.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_internaluser");
             GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_mom", ConditionOperator.Equal, RequiredAttendee["new_mom"]);
             GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_internaluser", ConditionOperator.Equal,user);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_actionitem", ConditionOperator.Null);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_discussionpoint", ConditionOperator.Null);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_externaluser", ConditionOperator.Null);

            EntityCollection GMA = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(GetMeetingAttendees);
            return (Guid)GMA[0]["new_internaluser"];
        }

        //Get Internal Meeting Attendee with Discussion Point
        public Guid VerifyDPMeetingAttendee(Entity RequiredAttendee, IOrganizationService _orgService, Guid user)
        {
            QueryExpression GetDPMeetingAttendees = new QueryExpression();
            GetDPMeetingAttendees.EntityName = "new_requiredattendee";
            GetDPMeetingAttendees.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_internaluser");
            GetDPMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_mom", ConditionOperator.Equal, RequiredAttendee["new_mom"]);
            GetDPMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_internaluser", ConditionOperator.Equal,user);
            GetDPMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_actionitem", ConditionOperator.Null);
            GetDPMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_discussionpoint", ConditionOperator.NotNull);
            GetDPMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_externaluser", ConditionOperator.Null);

            EntityCollection GMA = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(GetDPMeetingAttendees);
            return (Guid)GMA[0]["new_internaluser"];
        }

        //Get Internal Meeting Attendee with Action Items
        public Guid VerifyAIMeetingAttendee(Entity RequiredAttendee, IOrganizationService _orgService, Guid user)
        {
            QueryExpression GetDPMeetingAttendees = new QueryExpression();
            GetDPMeetingAttendees.EntityName = "new_requiredattendee";
            GetDPMeetingAttendees.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_internaluser");
            GetDPMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_mom", ConditionOperator.Equal, RequiredAttendee["new_mom"]);
            GetDPMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_internaluser", ConditionOperator.Equal,user);
            GetDPMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_actionitem", ConditionOperator.NotNull);
            GetDPMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_externaluser", ConditionOperator.Null);

            EntityCollection GMA = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(GetDPMeetingAttendees);
            return (Guid)GMA[0]["new_internaluser"];
        }

        //Get External Meeting Attendee
        public Guid VerifyExternalMeetingAttendee(Entity RequiredAttendee, IOrganizationService _orgService, Guid user)
        {
            QueryExpression GetMeetingAttendees = new QueryExpression();
            GetMeetingAttendees.EntityName = "new_requiredattendee";
            GetMeetingAttendees.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_externaluser");
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_mom", ConditionOperator.Equal, RequiredAttendee["new_mom"]);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_externaluser", ConditionOperator.Equal, user);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_actionitem", ConditionOperator.Null);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_discussionpoint", ConditionOperator.Null);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_internaluser", ConditionOperator.Null);

            EntityCollection GMA = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(GetMeetingAttendees);
            return (Guid)GMA[0]["new_externaluser"];

        }

        //Get External Meeting Attendee with Discussion Point
        public Guid VerifyEXDPMeetingAttendee(Entity RequiredAttendee, IOrganizationService _orgService, Guid user)
        {
            QueryExpression GetMeetingAttendees = new QueryExpression();
            GetMeetingAttendees.EntityName = "new_requiredattendee";
            GetMeetingAttendees.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_externaluser");
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_mom", ConditionOperator.Equal, RequiredAttendee["new_mom"]);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_externaluser", ConditionOperator.Equal, user);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_actionitem", ConditionOperator.Null);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_discussionpoint", ConditionOperator.NotNull);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_internaluser", ConditionOperator.Null);

            EntityCollection GMA = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(GetMeetingAttendees);
            return (Guid)GMA[0]["new_externaluser"];

        }

        //Get External Meeting Attendee with Action Item
        public Guid VerifyEXAIMeetingAttendee(Entity RequiredAttendee, IOrganizationService _orgService, Guid user)
        {
            QueryExpression GetMeetingAttendees = new QueryExpression();
            GetMeetingAttendees.EntityName = "new_requiredattendee";
            GetMeetingAttendees.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_externaluser");
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_mom", ConditionOperator.Equal, RequiredAttendee["new_mom"]);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_externaluser", ConditionOperator.Equal, user);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_actionitem", ConditionOperator.NotNull);
            GetMeetingAttendees.Criteria.AddCondition("new_internaluser", ConditionOperator.Null);

            EntityCollection GMA = _orgService.RetrieveMultiple(GetMeetingAttendees);
            return (Guid)GMA[0]["new_externaluser"];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and is this code throwing some kind of error? Or is it just not working as expected?

Comment: I cant able to delete the records, after code hits on sdk.delete its rolls back . I am not sure but may be there is a prompt that is disturbing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding the issue here, but here's my thoughts.

1) If it is rolling back the delete, then there is either an error with the delete or with cascading deletes underneath this one.  Providing the exception message would go a long way to helping us troubleshoot your problem.

2) You can make your code much more concise and readable using LINQ queries instead of the CRM QueryExpression.  Another area for improvement is the exact same code multiple times with 1 minor tweak - aka the branches for attributes.contains("new_internaluser") and attributes.contains("new_external") user could be much improved - see below).

```
//Add this method to the class
internal void deleteUser(string userString){
    user = ((EntityReference)eUser[userString]).Id;
    //Function to fetch the Meeting Attendee with the Above ID
    Guid VerifyAttendee = VerifyMeetingAttendee(eUser,_sdk,user);
    //If its the Meeting Attendee
    if (VerifyAttendee != null)
    {
        //Get the Attendee with its Discussion Point
        Guid AttendeewithDp = VerifyDPMeetingAttendee(eUser, _sdk, user);
        if (AttendeewithDp != null)
        {
            //Get the Attendee with Action item
            Guid AttendeewithAI = VerifyAIMeetingAttendee(eUser, _sdk, user);
            if (AttendeewithAI != null)
            {
                //DO your code here....................................
                _sdk.Delete("new_requiredattendee", AttendeewithAI);
            }
        }
    }    
} 

//And call it with these few simple lines within your main execute method:
    if (eUser.Attributes.Contains("new_internaluser"))
    {
        deleteUser("new_internaluser");
    }
    //If User Selects the Interner User for Deletion
    else if (eUser.Attributes.Contains("new_externaluser"))
    {
        deleteUser("new_externaluser");
    }
```